# Stumped with Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm stumped as to how to compare strings held in variables (or returned from methods) in RSpec.

```
describe "comparing strings" do 
  it "will compare with a variable" do
    a = "00001000"
    expect ( a ).to eq "00001000"
  end

  it "it will compare without a variable" do
    expect( "00001000" ).to eq "00001000" 
  end
end
```

leads to :

```
comparing strings
  will compare with a variable (FAILED - 1)
  it will compare without a variable

Failures:

  1) comparing strings will compare with a variable
     Failure/Error: expect ( a ).to eq "00001000"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to' for "00001000":String
     # ./run.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00074 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

Why does the first example fail, but the second pass?

Comment: try deleting the space between the `expect` and the `(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed space after `expect`, you shouldn't:

```
expect( a ).to eq '00001000'
```

with space it's equivalent to:

```
expect a.to eq '00001000'
```

so `to` method is called on `a` and raises `NoMethodError`.